# Use variable (in function) after function has been declared

Tags: javascript

I know I could just pass it as a parameter but as an effort to understand JS further, is there anything like this:

```js
function logIt() {
  console.log(x)
}

[0,1,2].forEach(x => logIt())
// x is not defined
```

Comment: yes. there is no 'x'

Comment: A short answer is NO.  You will have to pass the parameter.  `x` has got to have a scope.

Comment: Really ugly and don't try this at home!: `var x; [0, 1, 2].forEach(y => { x = y; logIt(); }`

Comment: Thanks everybody for all the replies! I haven't yet got enough reputation for my upvotes to be displayed...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually no. Function tries to find the variables in the scope and the above scopes where it was declared. In your case `logIt` is declared in the global scope and it tries to find `x` there, but your `x` is defined in the function scope which is passed to the `forEach`. In other words `logIt` doesn't look for its variable in the `x => logIt()` scope.

```
// Global scope, Look here, this is the scope where `logIt` was declared

function logIt() {
  // Look here, this is my scope
  console.log(x)
}

[0,1,2].forEach(x => {
   // Does not look here, it is not the scope where `logIt` was defined and not the global scope
   logIt();
})
```

Comment: Would be helpful to the O.P. if you expanded on the `.forEach`'s scope being separate from the global scope where `logIt` would end up looking for `x`. Your text somewhat talks about that, but is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 1):

Scope access has to do with the scope in which the function is **defined**, not the scope in which it is **used**. Since `x` does not exist in the scope in which `logIt()` is defined, it is unavailable inside the function unless it is passed in via an argument.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, no. A function can't reach out and access variables in the scope that *called* it.* Which is a Good Thing™. :-)

You *could* define a variable that both `logIt` and the anonymous `forEach` callback have access to, set the value of that variable in the callback, and use it in `logIt`:

```js
// DON'T DO THIS, KEEP READING
let x;

function logIt() {
  console.log(x)
}

[0,1,2].forEach(_x => {
    x = _x;
    logIt();
})
```

...but that would be a Bad Thing™ in most cases. We have function arguments for a reason. :-)

---

* *(It **can** access variables in the execution context for the scope where and when it was created [and the contexts containing that context], but that's different.)*

Comment: @Andreas: LOL, when I expanded the concise arrow function into verbose form, I automatically inserted the `return` to replace the implicit return, without looking at the broader picture that `forEach` ignores the return value anyway (and `logIt` doesn't return anything). How automatonic of me. :-) Fixed.